# what is the name of the formula $x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$, for every $n \geq 0$

Tags: derivatives

I am solving for $x^x = 100$, I found a solution that used $$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ for every  $n  \geq 0$ as the working equation in finding the value of $x$.

I want to know what is the name of that formula.

Comment: Newton-Raphson method of root approximation.

Comment: Here's a mathjax tutorial http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

It's called Newton's Method.

You can read more about it on here:

[Newton's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)